# sword and chalice attributes

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Bess holds the queenly hand, caresses the royal head and keeps the imperial body intimate company, suggesting that Elizabeth (the Queen) **abandoned the metaphoric sword but not the chalice.**"
What did they mean? this has to be some kind of attribute but I cannot resolve this riddle

http://www.nytimes.com/2007/10/12/movies/12gold.html?_r=0

Comment: There are a whole lot of attributes. For instance, this is Tarot symbolism, and sexual symbolism, and political symbolism, and religious symbolism. Enough to go around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elizabeth I is known as the Virgin Queen. The state of Virginia in the USA is named for her, as are the Virgin Islands (I believe). She got that name because she never married and never gave birth. She never took any male lover (that were proven--there were/are many rumors). I was taught that if she married, she feared her status and power as monarch would be diminished.

> abandoned the metaphoric sword but not the chalice.

In your quote, the sword is a metaphor for a penis (male lover) and the chalice for a vagina (female lover).

More context from the article:

> She may be a virgin or virginesque, but she’s far from cloistered. She surrounds herself with female pets (“My bitches wear my collars”), the loveliest of whom is Bess Throckmorton (Abbie Cornish). Bess holds the queenly hand, *caresses* the royal head and keeps the imperial body *intimate company*

In the world of the film, the queen does not spend her time alone. She has many female attendants/friends (the "pets") who "caress" her and keep her body "intimate company" (they have sex, but it might be off-screen--I have't seen the movie).

Answer (score 3):

As noted by Peter Morris-Keitel, Alexa Larson-Thorisch, and Audrius Dundzila in an [article on *Tristan und Isolde*](http://books.google.com/books?id=u2hWii55O1UC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=sword%20chalice%20male%20female&source=bl&ots=JTUq8_wVJ7&sig=p0qxxQrws3LLZA8z9IaxjvSYLqg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HhSDVL6ME474yQS7voHQCQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=sword%20chalice%20male%20female&f=false),“The feminist historian Riane Eisler defines the sword as a historically and culturally male symbol and the chalice as the female one.” Note that the “Bess” referred to is not the Queen herself but a particularly fetching lady-in-waiting; Dargis here suggests that the film insinuates that the Queen was abstaining from heterosexual but not from homosexual physical intimacy.

Answer (score 1):

Sword and chalice are conventional symbols for male/female sexuality. The suggestion of the passage is of lesbian sexuality.